# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/SpringSessionContext

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, hibernate-mapping

I am try to implement SpringMVC 4 and Hibernate 4 integration with annotation in my project  but I am getting this error:
***org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in com.config.ApplicationContextConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: Factory method 'getSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/SpringSessionContext***
My Config file is::

```
    import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Properties;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext;
import com.dao.UserDao;
import com.dao.UserDaoImpl;
import com.pojo.User;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.config")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ApplicationContextConfig {

    @Bean(name = "viewResolver")
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }
    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
         DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/usersdb");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("");

        return dataSource;
    }
    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "sessionFactory")
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {

        LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sessionBuilder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource);

        sessionBuilder.addAnnotatedClasses(User.class);

        return sessionBuilder.buildSessionFactory();
    }
    private Properties getHibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        return properties;
    }
    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager(
            SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager(
                sessionFactory);

        return transactionManager;
    }
    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "userDao")
    public UserDao getUserDao(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        return new UserDaoImpl(sessionFactory);
    }

}
```

Comment: What version of spring-orm are you importing?

Comment: If you are using Maven, can you show us the dependencies section of your pom.xml?

Comment: I am using spring orm 4.3.0 without Maven

Comment: I have included all the jars

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you need, but do not have `spring-orm-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar` on your classpath. (I have identified the 4.3.0 version, you may be using a different 4.X version).

If you are using Maven, add the appropriate dependency to your pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

If you are not using Maven, you can download the jar file [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm/4.3.0.RELEASE).

For information on setting the classpath see this section of the [Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html).

Comment: It didn't work after adding jar and I am not using Maven